# В пайтоне не выводит имя фамилию

Tags: python, telegram-bot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'привет'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}, {message.from_user.last_name}</b>'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<b>Hello</b>',  parse_mode = 'HTML')
    print(message)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Что значит «не выводит»? Что происходит вместо вывода?

Comment: а отчество выводит?

Comment: Вот вы заполнили переменную `mess`, а передать ее в `bot.send_message` не сделали :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'привет'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}, {message.from_user.last_name}</b>'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess,  parse_mode = 'HTML')
```

Попробуйте так, а вообще советую писать на aiogram ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Не подскажешь, пожалуйста, когда у человека нет либо имени или фамилии в телеграмм бот не работает для них

Comment: @КонстантинВишнёв Создайте новый вопрос и распишите подробней что Вам нужно, так будет удобней)